# Как вывести сумму ряда?

Tags: c++, математика

Дано:[image: Сумма ряда]

Вот мой код:

```
//найти сумму ряда
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    double x;
    cout << "x="; cin >> x;
    double a = -x * x * x / 2, S = a; //начальные значения

    cout << "i\ta\tS\n"; //заголовок таблицы
    cout << 1 << "\t| " << a << "\t| " << S << endl; //вывод 1-ого шага
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        a *= -x * x / (2 * i * (2 * i +1)); //i - ый член ряда
        S += a; // сумма
        cout << i << "\t| " << a << "\t| " << S << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том что выводится -4,а остальные выведенные значения сильно разнятся от табличных.Помогите исправить пожалуйста.
Upd:я ещё не нашёл решение...

Comment: `a *= -x * x / (2 * i * (2 * i -1));`

Comment: @AlexGlebe,при вашем дополнении получается -4;-3;-3;-3;-3.Это всё равно не до конца всё то что мне нужно,но уже почти верно

Comment: вроде пашет , смотрите https://godbolt.org/z/81hxfs

Comment: @AlexGlebe,да работает и даже верно,спасибо огромное за помощь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно записали рекуррентное соотношение.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// a[n] = -1^n * x^(2n+1) / (2n)!
// (2n)! = (2n-2)!*(2n-1)*2n
// Итак:
// a[0] = x
// a[i] = a[i-1] * -1 * x*x / ((2n-1)*2n)
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "n=";
    n = 5;// cin >> n;
    double x;
    cout << "x=";
    x = 2;// cin >> x;

    double a = x, S = 0; //начальные значения

    cout << "i\ta\tS\n"; //заголовок таблицы
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a *= -1 * (x*x) / (2*i*(2*i-1));
        S += a;
        cout << i << "\t| " << a << "\t| " << S << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

вопрос - зачем вы вынесли отдельно расчёт для n = 1, а не использовали его в основном цикле:

```
double S = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
...
}
```

а по остальному у вас просто реализована неправильная формула

решите задачу в лоб, не пытайтесь как-то завязаться на предыдущие расчеты:

`(-1)^n` - это просто `(n % 2) ? -1 : 1`

`x^(2n + 1)` - это `pow(x, 2*n + 1)`

ну а факториал лучше вычислять в отдельной функции - удобнее

не пытайтесь впихнуть все в одно место, меньше ошибок будет и больше понимания кода ;-)

код:

```
double factorial(const int value) {
    if ((value == 0) || (value == 1))
        return 1;

    double res = 1;
    for (int index = 2; index <= value; index ++) {
        res *= index;
    }

    return res;
}

double S = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    S += ((n % 2) ? -1 : 1) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1) / factorial(2 * n);
}
```

Comment: Такс у меня вот такая строчка вышла: a *= (n % 2) ? -1 : 1 * pow(x, 2 * n + 1);//i - ый член ряда @Zhihar

Comment: Юрий, скобки наше все, особенно когда с приоритетами еще не освоились (да и потом лучше использовать) `a *= ((n % 2) ? -1 : 1) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1);` но 1) вы забыли разделить на факториал 2) зачем выделаете `a *=` когда это отдельный член суммы  и надо просто `a = ... `

Comment: Факториал 2 = 1*1*2?Или как это правильно записывается в с++?@Zhihar

Comment: факториал 2 = 1 * 2 = 2, что значит записывается? в c++ придется написать отдельную функцию для факториала!

Comment: Ладно,хорошо,я всё равно не понимаю если писать для факториала то вот что будет:
```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
// Начало рекурсивной функции нахождения факториала
int factorial(int N)
{
 if(N==0) return 1;
 if(N==1) return 1;
 return N*factorial(N-1);
}
// Конец функции
 
int main()
{
 int N;
 cout << "N = ";
 cin >> N;
 
 if(N >= 0)
 {
  cout << factorial(N); // Передаем функции N и выводим результат
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "Error: N < 0.";
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```
А как мне это всё вставить в мою формулу,не могу понять:( @Zhihar

Comment: добавил код в свой ответ - не понятно что там может быть непонятного - формула перед глазами, разбиваете ее на куски, находите куски и все вместе потом компануете

Comment: @Zhihar, вообще-то, весь смысл подобных заданий в том, чтобы вывести рекуррентное соотношение.. Если студент k раз вычисляет факториал и степень — это максимум тройка.

Comment: @vp_arth, так этого в задании сказано не было, это оговаривать тогда надо, а вообще если бы еще и k устремлять к бесконечности, то можно просто (cos(x) - 1)/x вычислять и не мучаться

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем в задании «У вас есть (n-1)!, вычислите n!» говорить о том, что не стоит с нуля вычислять весь факториал... Ну и да, шаблон кода в вопросе, как бы намекает, что этот вопрос оговаривался)